# Stripplot in MICE does not show categorical variables

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I´m using the `mice` package in R to do multiple imputation. I´ve done several imputations with only numerical variables, the imputation method is predictive mean matching, and when I use `stripplot(imp)` I get to see the observed and imputed values of all the variables.

The problem occurs when I impute a combination of categorical and numerical variables. The imputation method then is PMM for the numerical variables, and logistical regression for the categorical ones. Then, `stripplot` only shows me the numerical variables. Using the code below I tried to force `edu`, a categorical variable with 2 values, to be plotted:

```r
stripplot(imp, imp$edu)
stripplot(imp, names(imp$edu))
```

And I got this error:

> Error in stripplot.mids(imp, imp$edu) : Cannot pad extended formula.

Does anyone know how I can plot the values of the observed and the imputed values for both the numerical and the categorical variables?

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can try is to retrieve the imputed `dataset` as a data.frame and just use normal plotting functions. First retrieve the datasets including the original dataset with missing values (imp is the mice.mids object i.e. result of running mice)

```
impL <- complete(imp,"long",include = T)
```

Next add a dummy indicating which datasets are imputed

```
impL$Imputed <- factor(impL$.imp >0,labels = c("Observed","Imputed"))
```

Then you can just use plotting functions for each variable. This has the benefit that you can create nicer plots. For example using `ggplot` (package ggplot2) to create a barplot on a categorical variable:

```
ggplot(impL[which(!is.na(impL$var1)),],aes(x = var1)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = Imputed)) + facet_wrap(Imputed ~ .,ncol=1,nrow=2)
```

The `!is.na` is included to avoid the plotting of an NA bar. `var1` is the variable you want to plot. For a continuous variable you might create a density plot.

```
ggplot(impL, aes(x = var2, colour = Imputed)) + geom_density()
```

To look at all the unique imputations you can add `group = .imp` within the aes brackets. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, @Niek. However, the facetplot code gives an error: `"unexpected ',' in: ggplot(impL[which(!is.na(long_df$var1)),],aes(x = var1)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = Imputed)) + facet_wrap(Imputed ~,"` ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I forgot to add a `.` to the code. With `+ facet_wrap(Imputed ~ .,ncol=1,nrow=2)` this should work

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue, so I figured I might post an answer that achieves your goal without having to extract the imputed data.

```
library(mice)

# Create dataset holding numerical and categorical data
a <- as.factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5))
b <- rnorm(100, 5, 1)
df <- cbind.data.frame(a, b)

# Randomly assign 10 NA values to each column
df$a[sample(length(df$a), 10)] <- NA
df$b[sample(length(df$b), 10)] <- NA

# Impute with ppm and logreg
init = mice(df, maxit=0)
meth = init$method
meth['a'] <- 'logreg'
imp <- mice(df, method = meth)

# This only plots b, the numerical
stripplot(imp)

# This plots both, as included below
stripplot(imp, a + b ~ .imp)
```

[image]